# How to periodically refresh a partial view asp.net mvc applications?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my partial view called via a razor action call like below in my `_Layout` file code.

```
@Html.Action("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")
```

The `CartSummary` action in my controller is like below:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CartSummary()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
            {
                CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
            };

            return PartialView("CartSummary", viewModel);
        }
```

I'd like to refresh the partial view every second to reflect the changes made to the user cart. Currently when I add an item the whole page refreshes and I can see added items in my cart but when i remove item from cart as it is done by Ajax call the changes are not shown. How can i do that?
**EDIT for Stephen:**
I have a view (Main View) Called `CartIndex`, within this view i display users add items to his/her cart. The user can delete an item if he/she wants, The deletion of the item from cart is done with an ajax call within the `CartIndex` view. when the user deletes the items this CartIndex view shows that the item deleted successfully till here everything is fine. I have a partial view called `CartSummary` which displays summary of the cart like how many items are there in the users cart etc... The problem I have is that when the user remove item from `CartIndex` view the same should happen with the `CartSummary` so that they can display same amount of items and totals, but in my case the `CartIndex` view which is my main view shows the right data but the partial view is not updated? Below is the ajax call for removing the item from cart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".del-goods").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the item from the DOM in the ajax success callback (and why are you refreshing the whole page when a new item is added?)

Comment: How are you adding items to cart ? through a form submit or ajax call ?

Comment: @JSantosh through a form submit not ajax call. for what ever reason i don't need ajax call to add items through it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke because I want to redirect the user to a whole new url don't i need to refresh the whole page then?

Comment: @StephenMuecke how would you do it with removing the item from DOM in Ajax call back, noting that the ajax call back resting in a view rather than my partial view

Comment: @Dawar, Something like [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OCVF0q)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That is a great example but let say I have a partial view with the same view model with some minor changes in representing data from the main view. how can i reflect changes to that partial view when the user has deleted an item from the cart in the main view? do you get me?

Comment: @dawar I think you can't do it with out ajax call. By default fom submit refreshes the page. If you still don't want to use ajax call then use something like viewbag

Comment: @JSantosh It is already working fine with form submit the only concern is how can i refresh the partial or in other words how can i just update the partial view when an item is removed from the cart via ajax post ?

Comment: @Dawar, You can do what ever you want to the DOM in the success call back of the ajax call.

Comment: @StephenMuecke would it be a problem if you write an on the point answer? This way frankly i can't get anything out of it.

Comment: Impossible to give you an answer without knowing exactly what your wanting to do (you mentioned a partial in your previous comments but what is that partial, and what 'change' do you want to make to it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited the question would you please have a look?

Answer (score 2):

`@Dawar` as per your last comment `how can i refresh the partial or in other words how can i just update the partial view when an item is removed from the cart via ajax post ?`

**Html**

```
<div id="CartDiv"></div>
```

**C#**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RemoveItemFromCart(int itemId)
{  
    // Code to remove item from cart using the itemId
    List<Items> items=Get items from cart 
    return PartialView("_GetItemsInCart",items);// this is your partial view
}
```

**Javascript and Jquery**

```
function RemoveItemFromCart(itemId) {
// Show some loader image here
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/Cart/RemoveItemFromCart?itemId='+itemId,      
    success: function (data) {                      
        $("#CartDiv").html(data); 
        // hide the loader image here           
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I asume, you want to refresh a part of your html dom if the content of your shoppingcart changes.

There are several ways to solve your problem.

1. you could force a page reload after placing something in the cart (not the best way.)
2. you could send the content of the partial view as a result of the "placeItemInShoppingcart" process of your application and replace it using javascript.
3. You could use a timer  (as Sandip Patel suggested) to frequently check for an updated dom and replace it using javascript.
4. You could use signalR and register on a hub notification for shoppingcard changes. This way you only need to refresh the cartitems if there are actual changes AND you can use this on multiple open browser windows.

Though in conclusion you will always have to use javascript to replace the content. there is no C# only way to do this.

Additionaly you can switch to a javascript mvvm engine like knockoutjs or angular and just render the html on client side based on the javascript objects. this will actualy save some traffic and server load time.

Answer (score -1):

You can **call ajax call (CallPartiaView()) in timer** and rebind partialview. Take one div and place your initial partial view in it.

```
<div id="divPartialView">
  @Html.Action("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")
</div>

function CallPartiaView(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")',      
    success: function (data) {          
        $("#divPartialView").html('');
        $("#divPartialView").html(data);            
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
}
```